# How to increase the spaces between the items of `GridView` in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

How to increase the space between the items of a `GridView` in Windows 8?

Answer (score 20):

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 20 20"/>
   </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your statement...

> If we use the margin for spacing we can see the space between the
>   items but when we select any items the selection background will cover
>   the space between the items.

...as I just add **Margin** (say Margin="10") to only the *FIRST* **GridViewItem** and all subsequent items are evenly spaced.

code snippet-

```
        ... <GridView>
            <GridViewItem Margin="20" Width="100" Height="100">
                <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"/>
            </GridViewItem> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give margin to ItemContainerStyle. In Blend, right-click your grid, choose edit Additional Template -> Edit Generated Item Container. Give proper margin to OuterContainer component.

Answer (score 0):

Use margin for GridViewItem.

For example,

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle1" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-10,0,0"/> <!-- here -->
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" /> <!-- border-right, show infinity each items.-->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
    ...
</STyle>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create ItemTemplate and in it for every item use Margin. That way you`ll be able to spread them out

Comment: If we use the margin for spacing we can see the space between the items but when we select any items the selection background will cover the space between the items.

Comment: then try to use `GridView.CellSpacing`

Comment: GridView.CellSpacing is not an option in Winrt(windows 8). Can u please give me the full code